# Telerik scrollView not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I am making an app with the Telerik Platform. I have made everything but now the client wants a slider that shows 5 different news articles. I am trying to use the scroll view, but it isn't working. All I am getting is a black space where the slider should be.

This is what I have for the Html to call:

```
<div data-role="scrollview" 
        data-model="featured_articles_data" 
        data-template="featured_slider"
        data-content-height="13em">
    </div>
```

Here is my template:

```
<script id="featured_slider" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <a href="\\#">
            <div class="storyImg" style="background-image: url( #= data[0].thumbnail # ); margin-top: 0;"></div>
            <div class="blackBox">
                <div class="storyTitle">#= data[0].trunc_title #</div>
                <div class="timeStamp">#= data[0].article_date #</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="\\#">
            <div class="storyImg" style="background-image: url( #= data[1].thumbnail # ); margin-top: 0;"></div>
            <div class="blackBox">
                <div class="storyTitle">#= data[1].trunc_title #</div>
                <div class="timeStamp">#= data[1].article_date #</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="\\#">
            <div class="storyImg" style="background-image: url( #= data[2].thumbnail # ); margin-top: 0;"></div>
            <div class="blackBox">
                <div class="storyTitle">#= data[2].trunc_title #</div>
                <div class="timeStamp">#= data[2].article_date #</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="\\#">
            <div class="storyImg" style="background-image: url( #= data[3].thumbnail # ); margin-top: 0;"></div>
            <div class="blackBox">
                <div class="storyTitle">#= data[3].trunc_title #</div>
                <div class="timeStamp">#= data[3].article_date #</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="\\#">
            <div class="storyImg" style="background-image: url( #= data[4].thumbnail # ); margin-top: 0;"></div>
            <div class="blackBox">
                <div class="storyTitle">#= data[4].trunc_title #</div>
                <div class="timeStamp">#= data[4].article_date #</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

This is what I have for the app to pull the datasource:

```
featured_articles_data = new kendo.observable({ //featured_articles_data is initialized on the index page
        fNewsItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: serviceURL,
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "posts"
            }
        }),
        selectedStory: {},
        selectHeadline: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var story = e.dataItem;
            viewModelStory.set("selectedStory", story);
            var detailsPage = "#detailsPage";
            app.application.navigate(detailsPage.toString());
            app.application.scroller().reset();
        },
        resetScroller: resetScroller
    });
    featured_articles_data.fNewsItems.read();
```

The functions selected headline and selected story make it so when you click on the story it pulls up another page with the story content. I want the slide to rotate every 5 seconds.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using scroll view or is scroll view even what I am looking for?

Thank you in advanced.